# Removing HTML tags which contain ">" in them

Tags: html, regex, vb.net

im trying to remove HTML tags from a string which contains a ">" in between the HTML tags. I tried using regex, but it removes pieces of the string I want to keep.

Here is the string i'm trying to remove all the HTML tags from as an example. http://pastebin.com/0aqn12Gh

As you can see, there are comments within the tags made by users which contain ">" in them

So does anyone know how to do this using regex? Also im doing this in VB.net if there is anything better someone can recommend of doing this

Comment: Struggling to see any `>` that do not belong to a tag, see plenty of `&gt;` though. I might be misinterpreting what you are saying...

Comment: @OGHaza, I think the pastebin may have changed? I recall when initially following the link, those `&gt;`s were `>`, but it's possible my memory is just faulty.

Comment: Who knows, either way I expect in OPs actual data they appear as `>`.

Comment: Its hard to see the >, but they are under com. I'm basically grabbing posts from 4chan using their API. the thing is that the comments I'm extracting come with the HTML tags, and I want to remove them without removing any of the text. the > character is used a lot on 4chan to begin comments. Here is the above example string I want to remove HTML tags from http://pastebin.com/QhhKZJz1

Comment: I see no reason why my answer would not be working, why the unaccept? At least leave a comment so I can ammend. It removes all span and br tags in the text provided and any other tag that could possible appear for that mater. And @Brian-S I just spotted a `>` in the original code ;)

Comment: ah my bad. I thought it was not working when it actually was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are concerns that comments may contain > and < characters that are not part of tags, and you want to leave these intact. The following regex should do that:

```
<[^<>]*>
```

I don't personally know VB.net but from a quick google I'd say you need:

```
Regex.Replace(input, "<[^<>]*>", "");
```

[Working Example on RegExr](http://regexr.com?379ku) - you can set it to replace, and set the replace string to blank to see the output.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to parse some JSON data, so I'd recommend first and foremost parsing the JSON into an actual object.

```
Public Class User
    Private mPosts As Post()
    Property posts() As Post()
        Get
            Return mPosts
        End Get
        Set(ByRef Value as Post())
            mPosts = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class Post
    Private mNo As Integer
    Private mNow As String
    Private mName As String
    Private mCom As String
    Private mFilename As String
    Private mExt As String
    Private mW As Integer
    Private mH As Integer
    Private mTn_w As Integer
    Private mTn_h As Integer
    Private mTim As ULong
    Private mTime As Integer
    Private mMd5 As String
    Private mFsize As Integer
    Private mResto As Integer
    Private mBumplimit As Integer
    Private mImagelimit As Integer
    Private mReplies As Integer
    Private mImages As Integer

    Property no() As Integer
        Get
            Return mNo
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
            mNo = Value
        EndSet
    End Property

    Property now() As String
        Get
            Return mNow
        End Get
        Set(ByRef Value As String)
            mNow = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    ' Et Cetera
End Class
```

When you receive your JSON:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var userData = serializer.Deserialize<User>(jsonText);
```

Then, parse the "com" property of the JSON object, as that's where the HTML is located:

```
var cleanText = Regex.Replace(userData.posts[k].com, "<([^>]+)>", "");
' posts[k] is assuming you're iterating through the posts array with an iterator named k
```

*Disclaimer: VB.Net is not a language I'm accustomed to, so there may be syntax or style mistakes in the above code. I have never used JavaScriptSerializer before; my use in this code is based on reading documentation only.*

Answer (score 1):

Link http://regexr.com?379mn

If you just want to remove the immediate surrounding pair (looks like `span`) without removing the other tags, this could be a way as well.

Find:

```
 #  <[^<>]+>((?:(?:(?!<[^<>]+>|>).)*>(?:(?!<[^<>]+>|>).)*)+)<[^<>]+>

 < [^<>]+ >
 (
      (?:
           (?:
                (?! < [^<>]+ > | > )
                . 
           )*
           > 
           (?:
                (?! < [^<>]+ > | > )
                . 
           )*
      )+
 )
 < [^<>]+ >
```

Replace:  `$1`

Comment: +1 This one works as advertised. However, note that the pattern can be simplified (and sped up) to be just: `/<[^<>]+>([^<>]*(?:>[^<>]*)+)<[^<>]+>/`

Comment: @ridgerunner - Thanks! I initially thought about doing that, but I thought there could be a `<` between tags. But now that you mention it, I think `<` is illeagal between tags. So your solution is right for the job. I won't change it because its yours. You should post it.

Comment: This one removes the span ones perfectly. Now is there a way to also remove the href and <br> tags?